# 100% div inside li shows size more than li size

Tags: css

what i am doing wrong here why my div is in size more than the LI i have tested in chrome my text is very large and it goes out of the LI size and when i inspect element found that the size of DIV is not contained in LI

```
<ul class="aa">  
    <li>
        <div>
            my text is here loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum 
        </div>
    </li>
```

css style

```
.aa li
    {
        width:600px; list-style:none; display:block; margin:0px; padding:0px;
    }

.aa li div
    {
        width:100%;
        padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; margin:0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you add padding to something that's `width:100%` you make it more than `100%`.

The simple way to fix this is to remove the `width` from the `<div>`, or set it to `auto` if necessary.

Before: http://jsfiddle.net/VkJQu/

After: http://jsfiddle.net/VkJQu/1/

Comment: Yes, this. As a side note, it might be worth mentioning that the total width of an element = margin-left + border-left + padding-left+ width + padding-right + border-right + margin-right. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 0):

It is during padding is not zero, in default box-model ( content box ) width is set to content , so result width of element is 100 % + 20 px.

Solution is to use `box-model: border-box` property. Note - for mozilla and ie there is a prefix ( -ms- and -moz- ). Result css will be

```
.aa li
{
    width:600px; list-style:none; display:block; margin:0px; padding:0px;
}

.aa li div
{
    width:100%;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; margin:0px;
    box-model: border-box;
    -ms-box-model: border-box;
    -moz-box-model: border-box;
}
```

PS For IE you can hack this also by using quirks mode

Answer (score 0):

That's becase you've set padding to your div so the div is now 600px wide (100%) + 20px (left and right padding);